# Read external text file with header

Tags: matlab, sum, octave, names

I am attempting to read an external text data file into `Octave`.  The file contains two columns of numbers each with a variable name as a header.  Here are the contents of the file called 'simple_octave_dataset_with_names.txt':

```
     mycol1     mycol2
   0.632736  -0.097964
   0.410370   0.196382
   0.426642   1.011637
   0.135770  -0.112614
   0.034180  -0.874835
```

I can read the file using copy and paste in the `Octave GUI` like this if there are no column names:

```
chdir 'C:/Users/general1/Documents/simple Octave programs/'

myData = [
   0.632736  -0.097964
   0.410370   0.196382
   0.426642   1.011637
   0.135770  -0.112614
   0.034180  -0.874835
]

sum(myData)
#ans =
#
#   1.63970   0.12261
```

I can read the external file like this if there are no column names:

```
myexternalData = load('simple_octave_dataset.txt')
#myexternalData =
#
#   0.632736  -0.097964
#   0.410370   0.196382
#   0.426642   1.011637
#   0.135770  -0.112614
#   0.034180  -0.874835

sum(myexternalData)
#ans =
#
#   1.63970   0.12261
```

I can read the external data file like this if there are column names:

```
myexternalDatawithnames = importdata('simple_octave_dataset_with_names.txt', delimiterIn = ' ', headerlinesIn = 1)
```

However this does not work:

```
sum(myexternalDatawithnames)
# error: sum: wrong type argument 'scalar struct'
```

How can I sum the two columns when there are column names?  *Here is a **solution** I found to this question:*

```
sum(myexternalDatawithnames.data)
#ans =
#
#   1.63970   0.12261
```

How can I sum the two columns when referring to them by column names?

How can I sum just the first column when referring to it by name?

How can I add column names when using `load('simple_octave_dataset.txt')` and then sum the second column when referring to it by name?

How can I read the file using `C` syntax with and without column names?

Thank you for any help with these questions?  I know they are extremely basic.  I am an `R` user learning `Octave` and have tried to solve this problem on my own for quite a long time now.

Comment: What does "this does not work" mean?

Comment: It means it returns an error message rather than the desired column sums.

Comment: And the error message is...what? We are not omniscient.

Comment: The code is fully reproducible, but I will add the error message anyway.  I already posted the solution to that error message as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write simple script which assign data from file to variables with names from 1st line of file. Create script with name - **readfile.m**:

```
A=importdata(filename , ' ',1);
for k = 1 : length(A.colheaders)
%  A.colheaders{1,k} - name of column #k
%  A.data(:,k) -  data of column #k
  eval([A.colheaders{1,k} ' = A.data(:,' int2str(k) ');']);
end
clear A;
```

For demonstration work of script create text file with names '**simple_octave_dataset_with_names.txt**':

```
     mycol1     mycol2
   0.632736  -0.097964
   0.410370   0.196382
   0.426642   1.011637
   0.135770  -0.112614
   0.034180  -0.874835
```

Type in Matlab/Octave:

```
>> filename='simple_octave_dataset_with_names.txt';
>> readfile
>> mycol1, mycol2
mycol1 =

   0.632736
   0.410370
   0.426642
   0.135770
   0.034180

mycol2 =

  -0.097964
   0.196382
   1.011637
  -0.112614
  -0.874835
>> sum(mycol1)
ans =  1.6397
>> sum(mycol2)
ans =  0.12261
```

Answer (score 0):

If I know the variable names I can assign them manually with this:

```
[mycol1,mycol2] = textread ('simple_octave_dataset_with_names.txt', '%f %f', 'headerlines', 1, 'delimiter', ' ')

sum(mycol1)
#ans =  1.6397

sum(mycol2)
#ans =  0.12261
```

I would prefer not to have to assign the variable names manually, but rather extract them from the `importdata` `colheaders` cells.  If I figure out how to do that I will post the solution here.